# flex advanced datagrid single column

Tags: apache-flex, advanceddatagrid

i was working on Advanced Data-Grid i was set horizontal scroll policy into on and declared multiple columns so that i can see the horizontal scroll bar but i cant see the scroollbar for the particular column if the data is too large the text can be scrolled for the partiuclar column just like spark datagrid ...................................................................................................................................................................................................................

i was working on Advanced Data-Grid i was set horizontal scroll policy into on and declared multiple columns so that i can see the horizontal scroll bar but i cant see the scroollbar for the particular column if the data is too large the text can be scrolled for the partiuclar column just like spark datagrid .. Did anyone had the solution... ...................................................................................................................................................................................................................

i was working on Advanced Data-Grid i was set horizontal scroll policy into on and declared multiple columns so that i can see the horizontal scroll bar but i cant see the scroollbar for the particular column if the data is too large the text can be scrolled for the partiuclar column just like spark datagrid Did anyone had the solution... ...................................................................................................................................................................................................................

Comment: The horizontal scroll bar will be disabled (or not present, depending on the setting of horizontalScrollPolicy) until the minimum measured width of the columns exceeds the width of the AdvancedDataGrid.

Answer (score 0):

try to set horizontalScrollPolicy="auto"